# Delegate not working (Restkit related?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, restkit

I'm just getting started with Objective C and Restkit

I created a sample application and added the RKRequestDelegate in MyAppDelegate file

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, RKRequestDelegate> {…
```

and added

```
  RKClient* client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:3000"]; 
   NSLog(@"I am your RKClient singleton : %@", [RKClient sharedClient]);
   [client get:@"/titles.json" delegate:self];
```

to MyAppDelegate.m in the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method
```

I also added a method to MyAppDelegate.m

```
- (void) request: (RKRequest *) request didLoadResponse: (RKResponse *) response {
    if ([request isGET]) {        
        NSLog (@"Retrieved : %@", [response bodyAsString]);
    }
 }
```

so far so good everything is working and I see the results from my Rails app in the output!!!

As those things don't belong into MyAppDelegate.m I'm moving that stuff into my models. In my Titles.h I added

```
@interface Titles : NSManagedObject <RKRequestDelegate> {
```

and in Titles.m I added

```
+ (void) update {   
    [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/titles.json" delegate:self];
}
```

and

```
- (void) request: (RKRequest *) request didLoadResponse: (RKResponse *) response {
    if ([request isGET]) {
        NSLog (@"Retrieved : %@", [response bodyAsString]);
    }
}
```

In my MyAppDelegate.m I replaced :

```
 RKClient* client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:3000"]; 
   NSLog(@"I am your RKClient singleton : %@", [RKClient sharedClient]);
   [client get:@"/titles.json" delegate:self];
```

with

```
  RKClient* client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:3000"]; 
   NSLog(@"I am your RKClient singleton : %@", [RKClient sharedClient]);
  [Titles update];
```

when I run now I don't get any output.
I put several breakpoints, one in the `- (void)didFinishLoad:(RKResponse*)response` in the RKRequest file
and there the if test for :

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didLoadResponse:)]) {
        [_delegate request:self didLoadResponse:finalResponse];
    }
```

fails while it succeeds in my first attempt (when everything is in MyAppDelegate)

I checked the variable _delate in de debugger and it says: _delegate = MyAppDelegate in my first attempt and _delegate = Titles in my second attempt (both like it should)

Why does that respondsToSelector fail ? (the delegate is correct and the method exists in Titles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your trying to set a class as the delegate:

```
+ (void) update {   
  [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/titles.json" delegate:self];
}
```

`self` here is the *class* `Titles`.

The callback is (as expected), an instance method:

```
- (void) request: (RKRequest *) request didLoadResponse: (RKResponse *) response {
  if ([request isGET]) {
    NSLog (@"Retrieved : %@", [response bodyAsString]);
  }
}
```

You should have some kind of "DataModel" model class (perhaps "SongList" or whatever makes sense). This is often a singleton, so you have a `+sharedModel` instance. That instance is what is the delegate for `RKClient`.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob,  I did a little 
testing by making 'update' an instance method and creating an object 
 Titles *title = [Titles alloc]; 
    [title update]; 
and it works. 

 
However I don't understand your explanation of the DataModel class. Can you elaborate. My class Titles is an NSManagedObject (using Core Data) and it will store all titles for different Albums. The reason I used a class method is that making an object like I did in my testing is silly and not good design.

Comment: This is a strange design. Why do you have a special `NSManagedObject` that contains properties of other objects? This seems to be fighting Core Data. I would think you'd have a `Collection` or `AlbumCollection` that would hold the `Album` objects. And then you could use `[collection allTitles]` to return the titles if you need that as a string list.

Comment: My explanations wasn't very clear obviously...
I have the following classes: Artists (properties: name, stage_name, birthday,...) and a relation has_and_belongs_to_many Albums, Albums (properties: name, year, cover) has_many Titles ... All of them are NSManagedObjects. I wanted each of them to have a class method update, which I would call at the start of the application. That method would sync the data with a Rails App.

Comment: OK; so a "Title" is what a naive reader (me) would think of as a "Song" or "Track" :D But obviously there are many things on Albums that are not Songs, and "Track" probably just shows my age, so that makes sense.

Comment: hehe Rob, I'm not a native English speaker and probable also naive, guess Track might be a better description, I choose Title as in the title of a song (if that makes sense, it does in our language). Anyway I still don't know how to solve this without a class method...

Comment: Move all the updates into a `CollectionManager` singleton responsible for managing updates to everything. If you want to keep them separate, then create `AlbumManager`, `TitleManager`, and `ArtistManager` singletons to be responsible for "all instances of this class."